# Jsp project not showing on azure,how to deploy it correctly

Tags: azure, jsp, azure-web-app-service

I have a java jsp project need to upload to azure web apps. So I created web app service but in  ftp there is no web apps folder, so I created one but still I can't access it.Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your App Service Web App has Tomcat as the Java web server in general settings:

[image]

Then make sure your JSP files are copied under /wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/

You might need to restart the web app after your files are deployed

For more information, please check our quickstart and configuration guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java

Comment: I tried with both Tomcat 9 and 8.5. When I connect to the FTP, it opened wwwroot directly with a sample HTML and not webapps folder. So, I created the structure and copied my files there but it is same result, my site not accessible.

Comment: What do you see when you visit your web app from your browser? Do you see something that says "Hey, Java developers!"? Can you share the structure of your /home/site/wwwroot/webapps directory? Also, can you confirm that you have restarted the web app from the portal after copying the new content?

Comment: It is fixed by Microsoft support team, as there is some issue with server yesterday.